# Convert .db file to Text or CSV

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite ".db" file and I need to convert this into CSV or text format. This is on Unix and I am new to Unix. Any help would be appreciated. I don't want to install sqlite and script which I can run on Unix will be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask why don't you want to install sqllite? It would make things so much easier.

Comment: This is a class project where we have a lot of hdf5 files and couple of .db file.

Comment: Do you have the `sqlite3` command-line shell?

Comment: And... Why no sqllite, any problems installing it or learning it, pale into insignificance compared to binary parsing the db file. If I wanted to do that and there's no way I would, first thing I'd have to do would be install sqllite anyway...